# R create series several intervals

Tags: r

I have two columns of data where I want to single vector made up the intervals between the two values. Here is my data in `tbl`:

```
>tbl
A ,B
1 ,1
5 ,6
9 ,12
```

The result I want is:

```
1 , 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

My thought was that this should work but it does not:

```
tbl["A"]:tbl["B"]
```

Instead I get an error:

```
Error in tbl["A"]:tbl["B"] : NA/NaN argument
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
mapply(seq, tbl$A, tbl$B)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 5 6
#
# [[3]]
# [1]  9 10 11 12

unlist(mapply(seq, tbl$A, tbl$B))
# [1]  1  5  6  9 10 11 12
```